# Problem of appendix inside references

Tags: appendix

I am writing a paper and I have a section named appendix  where I have 2 tables. The problem is when I run latex, I got references inside appendix, I can't write all the code but the appendix part is like:

```
\section*{Appendix}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Table A}
\label{tab:Parameters}
begin{tabular}
 .....
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Table B}
\label{tab:Parameters}
begin{tabular}
 .....
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 

\bibliography{name of bib file}
```

Comment: Does the appendix section consist of just two `table` environments? Do they fit on one page? Please also clarify what you mean by "I got references inside appendix".

Comment: Yes only two tables. The tables are on one page . What I mean references inside appendix is that normally the references section is after the Appendix section. But in my case some references got inside my appendix

Comment: May be you have just to add the command `\clearpage` just before the `\bibliography` command (or at the point that your Appendix is supposed to end)

Comment: Thanks @koleygr it works

Comment: Welocme ... For your next question, keep in mind that I think you have to ping the user you are talking to by adding his nickname in your comment like "@kerdoujkardouj".... Happy TeXing! (I said that about not pinging Mico... but noticed you pinged me)